# Add location to to profile2 just after the user registers

Tags: 7, users, hooks, location

I am trying to force add a location to a user's profile2 just after the user register's an account. The user's are able to add locations to their profile by using flags, but since there are no locations just after the user registers, the rules add fails because the locations list has not been initiated.

The below code is what I currently have:

```
if (isset($account->is_new) && !empty($account->is_new)) {
  function user_account_presave_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) { 
    global $user;

    // Load profile2.
    $profile = profile2_load_by_user(array('type' => 'next', 'uid' => $user >uid));

    // Add in the necessary custom fields and values.
    $profile->field_next_destination['und'][] = array(
      'longitude' => '0.0',
      'latitude' => '0.0',
    );

    // Save the profile2 to the user account.
    profile2_save($profile);

  }
}
```

I am not sure if the IF statement should be in the Function, but if it is not, the Function fails to allow users to register because the CAPTCHA reuse attack function is triggered.

Has anyone ever run into this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`hook_user_insert`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_insert/7.x) instead. The `$account` will have `$account->uid` set at that stage.

P.S wrapping `hook_user_presave` in that condition looks wrong and probably won't work with the hook registry cache.

Comment: I am still getting a "CAPTCHA session reuse attack detected."

Comment: "CAPTCHA session reuse attack detected" is a different issue, probably related to caching of the page/form where the captcha is being shown. see `_captcha_get_posted_captcha_info` for the related code.

Comment: I have turned off recaptcha in an attempt to isolate the issue as well as use user_insert, but it doesn't seem like it it currently doing anything. Will be doing a db_insert be what I have to do?

Comment: If the Profile2 profile hasn't been created, you may need to create it with [`profile2_create`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21profile2%21profile2.module/function/profile2_create/7)

Comment: I am unfortunately not gaining any traction on this.

Comment: Where am I going wrong in the below?
   `function user_account_presave_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
      global $user;
      $profile = profile2_load_by_user($user->uid, 'main');
      if (!$profile) {
        $profile = profile2_create(array('user' => $user, 'type' => 'main'));
        $profile->field_test_text['und'][0]['value'] = "test";
        profile2_save($profile);
      }
    }`

Comment: As mentioned above, try `hook_user_insert` not `hook_user_presave` also use the `$account` parameter, not `global $user` because the user account being updated may not always be the current logged in user (e.g admin other user update) You might also need to set `$account->profiles['main'] = $profile;` but could be automatic on next load with uid set.

Comment: Shortly after I submitted the above comment I realized the hook_user_presave mistake I made. You are very right about that. It appears I have having difficulty with the $account variable. It seems as if it is empty at this point. Is there a way I can set it safely? I have everything working when I use hook_user_update very well. Thank you